# bogus page unresponsive error from google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome is popping up with this message every minute or so and it's quite annoying. More so because the pages *are* responsive. I mean if the pages weren't responsive that'd be one thing and I'd be very appreciative of the popup but as is they are perfectly responsive.

Screenshot:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: is it only on cpanel pages? There may be a cpanel bug or process which takes longer than some fixed timer which chrome uses to decide if there is a runaway script

Answer (score 2):

I understand it is a Chrome bug which is in the process of being fixed. However, I managed to clear it by updating my version of Java. I don't know if this will help you, but worth a try.